# iOS application stops sending location updates after some period of time while the app is in the background

Tags: ios, core-location

I have an iOS that needs to receive continuous location updates in the background.  I set the location manager as follows:

```
location_manager.delegate = self
location_manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
location_manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest   
location_manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
location_manager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

When I move the application to the background, it will periodically stop receiving location updates.  It is inconsistent as to when it stops receiving updates.

The app remains running in the background and can be brought to the foreground, at which time location updates will resume.

Comment: i have a heartbeat log event that writes to a log every minute and events showing when the app goes to background and foreground

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution may be these additional configuration properties to the location manager:

```
location_manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
location_manager.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation
```

Still test but looks good.

Perhaps only 1 of these is necessary to solve my problem.  But setting both at least seems to solve the problem.